# Output file contains extra zeros

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have a little problem with this simple Fortran program

```
PROGRAM Calc_U0
Implicit None
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: x,y
integer :: n=16589,m=9,nm=6,I,J,r

open (unit = 7, file = "U0.txt")
open (unit=99, file='slice06.txt', status='old', action='read')

allocate(x(n,m))
allocate(y(n,nm))

do I=1,n
  read(99,*,END=71) x(I,:)
enddo

71 do I=1,n
  print*,I
  do J=1,n
     if(I/=J) then
       !! if(x(I,1)==x(J,1)) then
         if(x(I,2)==x(J,2)) then
           if(x(I,3)==-x(J,3)) then
              y(I,1)=x(I,1)
              y(I,2)=x(I,2)
              y(I,3)=x(I,3)
              y(I,4)=(x(I,7)+x(J,7))/2
              y(I,5)=(x(I,8)+x(J,8))/2
              y(I,6)=(x(I,9)+x(J,9))/2
              write(7,*) (y(I,r),r=1,6)
           endif
         endif
       !!endif
     endif

  enddo

enddo

END PROGRAM Calc_U0
```

Everything seems to work fine, until I look at file `U0.txt`. This file contains my result plus other rows of zeros (millions), with a size of 6.4 GB. But I do not understand where the bug is, because if I read less than 8000 rows this problem disappear. I'm on Linux with gfortran compiler.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran]. Choose a title which describes your problem, not just the topic. The topic is described by the tags.

Comment: Since `16589**2` is just north of `275*10**6` it would not be surprising if that program writes a very large file when the `if` statements inside the nested loop evaluate to `.true.`.  I conclude that this is a data issue, not a programming problem.

Comment: Do you have access to a modern Fortran compiler (2008+)? If so, please use the `newunit` specifier instead of hard-coding file identifier units.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many rows you read; your loops still go from 1 through 16589.  Perhaps you should change n in those loops to be the actual number of rows you read.